# created calculated field from summarized data

Tags: powerbi, dax

This question is regarding PowerBI and DAX. I have two tables relevant to this question. The first a customer list, including addresses. The second is a geospatial reference table. The reference table has the square mileage of various zip codes. I'm looking to create a density field, which would be the number of customers in a zip code divided by the sq/mi of that zip code. I feel like this is a two-step process, first summarizing the customer count by zip, and then calculating the density. I can't seem to figure out a way of doing it outside of creating another table. Is this something I can do on the fly? I ask because my customer list will change frequently enough that creating that intermediate table could be a bit of an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Is it not simply:

```
Density = 
DIVIDE ( 
    COUNTROWS ( 'Customer Table' ),
    SUM ( 'Geospatial Reference Table'[Area] ),
    BLANK()
)
```

With a relationship between `Customer Table` and `Geospatial Reference Table` on field `Zip`

Here's a worked example PBIX file: https://pwrbi.com/so_55347190/